# javascript doesn't work, even in fiddle let alone the browser

Tags: javascript, html

here is my code for a simple playlist generator. but the javascript doesn't works at all as if it's not there.
i tried to run the code normally in the browser without any local host. But i learned that running javascript without a local host can cause problems so i tried to run in fiddle but it didn't worked there as well.

Any help would be highly valued.
Thanks.

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  window.onload = inti;

function init() {
  var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
  button.onclick = createPlaylist;
}

function createPlaylist() {
  var songText = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
  var songName = songText.value;
  var li = createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = "songName";
  var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
  ul.appendChild("li");
}

</script>
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="songTextInput" name="song" size="40" placeholder="song name">
    <input type="button" id="addButton" name="add" value="addSong">

    <ul class="playlist">

    </ul>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You've got errors. Have you even checked the console? Also where is the `createElement` function?

Comment: There is a type  window.onload = inti should probably refer to "init".

Comment: also remove `script` tags

Comment: No reason to have `onload` just put your script at the end and call init at the end of your script. It's `init` no `inti` and there's no function `createElement`. It's `document.createElement`

Comment: :)  :)  :)  points noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So many bugs. Did you bother to run it? Most of the issues showed up in the JavaScript console or here on stackoverflow in the snippet editor when run

Issues:

- No need for script tags on stackoveflow (though you need them outside stack overflow)
- It's `init` not `inti`
- It's `document.createElement` not `createElement`
- `songname` not `"songname"`
- `li` not `"li"`
- You marked the playlist with a class "playlist" so you want `document.querySelector(".playlist")` not `document.getElementById("playlist")`

Other recommendations

- You don't need `type="text/javscript"` as that's the default
- You don't need `window.onload` just put your script tag at the end and call `init` yourself.
- Consider never using `getElementById` and always use `querySelector`

  querySelector takes a CSS selector.  So

  ```
  document.querySelector("#foo")   // gets 1st element with id="foo"
  document.querySelector(".foo")   // gets 1st element with class="foo"
  document.querySelector("canvas") // get first canvas element
  ```

  etc... You can get [much more creative with selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors)

```js
function init() {
  var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
  button.onclick = createPlaylist;
}

function createPlaylist() {
  var songText = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
  var songName = songText.value;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = songName;
  var ul = document.querySelector(".playlist");
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

init();
```

```html
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="songTextInput" name="song" size="40" placeholder="song name">
    <input type="button" id="addButton" name="add" value="addSong">

    <ul class="playlist">

    </ul>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks. point noted. From now on would use  querySelector instead of getElementById.

Comment: Great answer with full explain.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to place `<script></script>` tags inside a js file or in js area in the Stack Snippet. It will be automatically detected as `JavaScript` code.

Then you have a typo in `window.onload=inti` it should be `init`.

Instead of `<ul class` , use `<ul id` because you call `document.getElement**ById**` in JavaScript.

*But i learned that running javascript without a local host can cause problems*

**Totally disagree.**

JavaScript is a client-side front end language, compiled by browser at run time. You don't need a Server/ host for running JavaScript. Even typing it in the browser console(f12) will run.

> Console is a good place to identify the error by yourself. Make use of it.

```js
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
  button.onclick = createPlaylist;
}

function createPlaylist() {
  var songText = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
  var songName = songText.value;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = "songName";
  var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
  ul.appendChild("li");
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="songTextInput" name="song" size="40" placeholder="song name">
    <input type="button" id="addButton" name="add" value="addSong">

    <ul id="playlist">

    </ul>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Too much bug.

I fix at here:

```js
window.onload = init();

function init() {
  var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
  button.onclick = createPlaylist;
}

function createPlaylist() {
  var songText = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
  var songName = songText.value;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = "songName";
  var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="songTextInput" name="song" size="40" placeholder="song name">
  <input type="button" id="addButton" name="add" value="addSong">

  <ul id="playlist">

  </ul>
</form>
```

First:

`init` # `inti`.

Second:

```
ul.appendChild(li);
```

#

```
ul.appendChild("li");
```

Using `""` with String. When call variable, don't use `""`.

More and more.

Comment: ok. thanks for your time. would look code closely for spelling mistakes. :)

Comment: @sarj7 Have many bugs in your code. I think you should debug in browser each error and search in StackOverflow to find the solution. If can't fix, you post your question at here. You have -5 downvotes because of this reason. At next time, please check before asking a question. And I see the answer of @gman is useful with good explain. Please accept his answer. Because other people will see this answer is accepted as first if people have the same issue as you, you should do `accept answer` instead of thanks. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has been a little bit messy, just it.

Please compare what I have posted below and this should to be clear why code wasn't running.

```
   <script type = "text/javascript" >
  window.onload = init();

    function init() {
      var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
      button.onclick = createPlaylist;
}

    function createPlaylist() {
      var songText = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
      var songName = songText.value;
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = songName;
      var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
      ul.appendChild(li);
      songText.value = '';
}
</script>
 <body>
   <form>
       <input type="text" id="songTextInput" name="song" size="40" placeholder="song name">
       <input type="button" id="addButton" name="add" value="addSong">

       <ul id="playlist"> </ul>

  </form>


</body>
```

and in relation to the post above
3rd:

```
var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
```

so:

```
<ul id="playlist"> </ul>
```

instead of:

```
<ul class="playlist"> </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate your effort.